# Highcharts Datetime axis issue

Tags: jquery, datetime, highcharts

I've setup my highchart options, such that my a-axis uses datetime. My data points are milliseconds and a number (x,y) -> (utcDate,number).

```
options.series.push({
  type: "line",
  name: "Performance",
  data: dataPoints,
  color: "#FF8000"
});
```

my options include:

```
xAxis: {
  type: "datetime",
  dateTimeLabelFormats: {
    day: "%e. %b",
    month: "%b '%y",
    year: "%Y"
  },
  lineWidth: 2
}
```

[image]

The problem is: I want my chart to show my first and last label: 1. Aug & 31. Aug.

I've tried using showFirstTick, showFirstLabel, and pointStart but that doesn't work. I can't set the interval, because my chart can show anything from weeks to months to years and would cause too much clutter.

Comment: Have you also tried the `startOnTick` or `tickmarkPlacement` option for the xAxis?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think whats happening here is that the x-axis selects to show weeks ([formatter selection described here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7101464/how-to-get-highcharts-dates-in-the-x-axis/7104992#7104992)) instead of months. The formatter patterns are merged together with the default ones, so there will still be a pattern for weeks even if it is left out from your options. Also check the `startOfWeek` option ([reference](http://www.highcharts.com/ref/#xAxis--startOfWeek)) where you set whether the week starts on Sundays or Mondays, defaults to Mondays.
(don't know of any way to turn off a certain level without editing the source)

Comment: I've marked this as the answer, as in normal circumstances it would be. My problem was from a custom hack to the .js file.