# Highcharts x-axis format data according to random min intervals

Tags: highcharts

[Here (jsfiddle)](http://jsfiddle.net/CYJAk/1) is my code with data. The graph generated is pretty messy can someone help me on this?

My data is at intervals like following:

```
hours:mins
10:13
15:15
18:14
22:13
00:13
```

at random time.

I have converted them to milliseconds, no problem with that, but to show them in Highcharts there's some problem in it, may be I didn't call req functions to format data to show proper in here or something.

Some dates in understandable format:

```
Tue Nov 08 10:13:00 IST 2011
Tue Nov 08 15:15:00 IST 2011
Tue Nov 08 18:14:00 IST 2011
Tue Nov 08 22:13:00 IST 2011
Wed Nov 09 00:13:00 IST 2011
Wed Nov 09 03:13:00 IST 2011
Wed Nov 09 06:13:00 IST 2011
Wed Nov 09 10:13:00 IST 2011
Wed Nov 09 15:13:00 IST 2011
Wed Nov 09 18:13:00 IST 2011
Wed Nov 09 22:13:00 IST 2011
Thu Nov 10 00:13:00 IST 2011
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Highstock requires the time data to be sorted. Adding this before the rendering solves your problem:

```
data.sort(function (a, b) {
    return a[0] - b[0];
});
```

Updated example: http://jsfiddle.net/CYJAk/3/

Comment: thank you :)
BTW how to show minutes also in x-axis or atleast in tooltip
because it specifies exact time of data right,otherwise it will indicates just data is in just between x and y time

Comment: Check this answer for how labels on datetime axes works: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7101464/how-to-get-highcharts-dates-in-the-x-axis/7104992#7104992