# Show 12 hrs time on xAxis in Highchart

Tags: jquery, highcharts, bar-chart

I am not much aware of the Highcharts

I need to show time as "9:00AM" on xAxis on highchart currently its showing "00:00".. I know I am missing something very obvious here

http://jsfiddle.net/r6emu/2643/

```
 xAxis: {
        //startOfWeek: 1,
        type: 'datetime',
        dateTimeLabelFormats: {
                hour: '%H:%M',
            },

        labels: {
            formatter: function () { 
                console.debug(this.value)

                return  Highcharts.dateFormat( '%H:%M',(this.value));
            }
        }
    },
```

Comment: `%l:%M %p` for example. [See this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/7104992/2732991).

Comment: **`this.value`** here doesn't contain time value, only date. All your data contain only dates, not hours.

Comment: Can I get Time from this.value then?

Comment: I can get the Time like this `new Date(this.value).format("%H %M")` 
but it shows error `(intermediate value).format is not a function` when used in place of `return  Highcharts.dateFormat( '%H:%M',(this.value));`

Comment: **`format`** is not defined in the Date of jsfiddle. It is irrelevant anyway. All **`this.value`** data has the time **0:0** - http://jsfiddle.net/r6emu/2645/ -

Comment: I think that [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/r6emu/2646/) should explain a bit more. Data on the chart is mainly daily-based. If you replace with "%H:%M", then it will display "00:00", because tickmark on xAxis is displayed at midnight. You can set offset for ticks, to display them translated by 9hours, but I think there may not be perfect solution with actual data (display 9AM with daily data). Example for offset in tickPositioner: http://jsfiddle.net/r6emu/2648/