# How to change time in hours on HighChart xAxis from Military to Standard time?

Tags: javascript, charts, highcharts

http://jsfiddle.net/leongaban/gbqvv0y9/

I've tried to edit the `dateTimeLabelFormats` key to have the chart use the much more readable Standard time, however no results...

[image]

```
$(function () {
    $('#container').highcharts({
        chart: {
            type: 'spline'
        },
        title: {
            text: 'Wind speed during two days'
        },
        subtitle: {
            text: 'May 31 and and June 1, 2015 at two locations in Vik i Sogn, Norway'
        },
        xAxis:[{
            dateTimeLabelFormats: {
                hour: '%H:%M'
            },
            type: 'datetime',
            labels: {
                overflow: 'justify'
            }
        }],
        yAxis: {
            title: {
                text: 'Wind speed (m/s)'
            },
            minorGridLineWidth: 0,
            gridLineWidth: 0,
            alternateGridColor: null,
            plotBands: [{ // Light air
                from: 0.3,
                to: 1.5,
                color: 'rgba(68, 170, 213, 0.1)',
                label: {
                    text: 'Light air',
                    style: {
                        color: '#606060'
                    }
                }
            }, { // Light breeze
                from: 1.5,
                to: 3.3,
                color: 'rgba(0, 0, 0, 0)',
                label: {
                    text: 'Light breeze',
                    style: {
                        color: '#606060'
                    }
                }
            }, { // Gentle breeze
                from: 3.3,
                to: 5.5,
                color: 'rgba(68, 170, 213, 0.1)',
                label: {
                    text: 'Gentle breeze',
                    style: {
                        color: '#606060'
                    }
                }
            }, { // Moderate breeze
                from: 5.5,
                to: 8,
                color: 'rgba(0, 0, 0, 0)',
                label: {
                    text: 'Moderate breeze',
                    style: {
                        color: '#606060'
                    }
                }
            }, { // Fresh breeze
                from: 8,
                to: 11,
                color: 'rgba(68, 170, 213, 0.1)',
                label: {
                    text: 'Fresh breeze',
                    style: {
                        color: '#606060'
                    }
                }
            }, { // Strong breeze
                from: 11,
                to: 14,
                color: 'rgba(0, 0, 0, 0)',
                label: {
                    text: 'Strong breeze',
                    style: {
                        color: '#606060'
                    }
                }
            }, { // High wind
                from: 14,
                to: 15,
                color: 'rgba(68, 170, 213, 0.1)',
                label: {
                    text: 'High wind',
                    style: {
                        color: '#606060'
                    }
                }
            }]
        },
        tooltip: {
            valueSuffix: ' m/s'
        },
        plotOptions: {
            spline: {
                lineWidth: 4,
                states: {
                    hover: {
                        lineWidth: 5
                    }
                },
                marker: {
                    enabled: false
                },
                pointInterval: 3600000, // one hour
                pointStart: Date.UTC(2015, 4, 31, 0, 0, 0)
            }
        },
        series: [{
            name: 'Hestavollane',
            data: [0.2, 0.8, 0.8, 0.8, 1, 1.3, 1.5, 2.9, 1.9, 2.6, 1.6, 3, 4, 3.6, 4.5, 4.2, 4.5, 4.5, 4, 3.1, 2.7, 4, 2.7, 2.3, 2.3, 4.1, 7.7, 7.1, 5.6, 6.1, 5.8, 8.6, 7.2, 9, 10.9, 11.5, 11.6, 11.1, 12, 12.3, 10.7, 9.4, 9.8, 9.6, 9.8, 9.5, 8.5, 7.4, 7.6]

        }, {
            name: 'Vik',
            data: [0, 0, 0.6, 0.9, 0.8, 0.2, 0, 0, 0, 0.1, 0.6, 0.7, 0.8, 0.6, 0.2, 0, 0.1, 0.3, 0.3, 0, 0.1, 0, 0, 0, 0.2, 0.1, 0, 0.3, 0, 0.1, 0.2, 0.1, 0.3, 0.3, 0, 3.1, 3.1, 2.5, 1.5, 1.9, 2.1, 1, 2.3, 1.9, 1.2, 0.7, 1.3, 0.4, 0.3]
        }],
        navigation: {
            menuItemStyle: {
                fontSize: '10px'
            }
        }
    });
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change `hour: '%H:%M'` to `hour: '%I:%M %P'`. Here is the [updated fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Pugazh/gbqvv0y9/3/).

For more formats refer - http://php.net/manual/en/function.strftime.php

Answer (score 1):

Just figured it out! [How to get highcharts dates in the x axis?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7101464/how-to-get-highcharts-dates-in-the-x-axis)

```
dateTimeLabelFormats: {
    hour: '%I:%p'
}
```

---

Update! This is the new way to swap Military time to Standard time:

```
dateTimeLabelFormats : {
    hour: '%I %p',
    minute: '%I:%M %p'
}
```

Comment: You're missing the minutes placeholder (%M) !!